# $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\in T^* \iff a,d \in R^*$ where $T=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d \end{pmatrix} \in M(2,R)\right\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with $1 \neq 0$ and the subring of $M(2,R)$

$$T=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in M(2,R)\right|c=0\right\}$$

Prove that $ \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \in T^*  \iff a \in R^* $ and $d \in R^*$

My try:

I already proved ($\implies$)

If $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \in T^*$, then there exist $A'= \begin{pmatrix}a' & b' \\ 0 & d' \end{pmatrix} \in T^*$ s.t $A.A'=A'A=I$

So from

$AA'= \begin{pmatrix} aa' & ab'+bd' \\ 0 & dd' \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$A'A= \begin{pmatrix} a'a & a'b+b'd \\ 0 & d'd \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

it follows that $aa'=a'a=1$ and $dd'=d'd=1$, so $a,d \in R^*$

I am having trouble with ($\impliedby$)

If $a,d \in R^*$, then $aa'=a'a=1$ and $dd'=d'd=1$, so for $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$, there must exist an inverse  $A'= \begin{pmatrix}a' & b' \\ 0 & d' \end{pmatrix}$ so I have to prove that $AA'=A'A=I$

$AA'= \begin{pmatrix} aa' & ab'+bd' \\ 0 & dd' \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & ab'+bd' \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$A'A= \begin{pmatrix} a'a & a'b+b'd \\ 0 & d'd \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a'b+b'd \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

I can't prove that $ab'+bd'=0$ and $a'b+b'd=0$. Although all I was able to prove regarding them is that $ab'+bd'=0 \iff a'b+b'd=0$. How do I do this?

Comment: Recall from linear algebra the formula for the inverse of a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: @DouglasMolin I am not sure if I can use these linear algebra stuff that are valid with fields. What about  my solution below? Is it OK?

Comment: What does $T^*$ denote?

Comment: @LeeMosher The group of  units (invertible elements) of the ring

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer:

Continuing with the proof above

Since $a'$ and $d'$ are already fixed to be $a'=a^{-1}$ and $d'=d^{-1}$. I can still choose $b'$ such that $ab'+bd'=0$ and $a'b+b'd=0$.

From the first one $b'=-a^{-1}bd'=-a^{-1}bd^{-1}$. From the second one the same result is obtained. Therefore $A'=\begin{pmatrix} a^{-1} &-a^{-1}bd^{-1} \\ 0 & d^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$ is the inverse of A. Because I have found that $A$ has an inverse, $A \in T^*$

Answer (score 0):

If $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}$ has inverse $B=\begin{pmatrix}p&q\\r&s\end{pmatrix}$, then $AB=1$ gives $ds=1$ and $BA=1$ gives $pa=1$. Moreover, from $AB=1$ we get $pb+qd=0$, and hence $q=-pbs$. There are further conditions, but it is not true that $a,d$ are invertible (and $r=0$).

One example would be to take the 'shift algebra' $R=k\langle x,y\rangle/(1-xy)$. Then $e=1-yx$ is a proper idempotent ($e\neq0,1$ and $e^2=e$) satisfying $xe=0=ey$. The matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}y&e\\0&x\end{pmatrix}$ then has inverse $B=\begin{pmatrix}x&0\\e&y\end{pmatrix}$.

For the other direction, suppose both $a$ and $d$ are invertible, with respective inverses $p,s$. Set $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}p&-pbs\\0&s\end{pmatrix}$. Then it is easy to check that $AB=1=BA$.

Comment: I call $R$ the shift algebra, since it acts on infinite sequences $a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots)$ via $xa=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ and $ya=(0,a_0,a_1,\ldots)$. Then $xy=1$ but $yxa=(0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ is not invertible, and $e=1-yx$ acts as $(a_0,a_1,\ldots)\mapsto(a_0,0,0,\ldots)$.