# $ T^*$ is commutative $\iff R^*=\{1\}$ where $T=\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in M(2,R)|c=0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with $1 \neq 0$ and the subring of $M(2,R)$

$$T=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in M(2,R)\right|c=0\right\}$$

Prove that $ T^*$ is commutative $\iff R^*=\{1\}$.

My try:

This is the follow-up from this question
[$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\in T^* \iff a,d \in R^*$ where $T=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d \end{pmatrix} \in M(2,R)\right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807412/beginpmatrixab-0d-endpmatrix-in-t-iff-a-d-in-r-where-t-left) where I proved  that

$ \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \in T^*  \iff a \in R^* $ and $d \in R^*$

($\implies$)

$AA'=A'A \forall 
A, A'\in T^*$

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \in T^*$ and
$A'= \begin{pmatrix}a' & b' \\ 0 & d' \end{pmatrix} \in T^*$

I know from the link above that $a,d,a',d' \in R^*$
From the condition

$AA'=A'A $

$ \begin{pmatrix} aa' & ab'+bd' \\ 0 & dd' \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a'a & a'b+b'd \\ 0 & d'd \end{pmatrix}$

it follows that

$aa'=a'a, dd'=d'd$ and

$ab'+bd'=a'b+b'd$

**I am stuck here, what can I do with this to conclude that $R^*=\{1\}$ ? And how can I prove the converse?**

Note: T* means the group of units of T

Comment: The converse is easy to show since it is just the unipotent group of upper triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: @Dian_Horton92 Thanks, I see your point, I had to used the result of the linked question to know that a and d have to be units of R. What do you mean with unipotent?

Comment: [Unipotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipotent) matrices.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \in R^* \setminus \{1\}$, then $\text{diag}(1,a)$ is invertible, but won't commute with $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

The converse can be done by explicitly writing out the product $\begin{pmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, or you can notice that $T^*$ is a subset of the commutative ring $\Bbb Z$-spanned by the identity and $\begin{pmatrix}0 & R \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. (Note that $R$ need not be commutative!)